# Make a bot assign role on member joining

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to write code that when a person joins the server they are automatically get assigned a role. I am not getting any error messages but the role is still not being assigned. I have also tried other variants and they have not worked.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random


client = discord.Client()
guest = 955210150485057627

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.add_roles(member.guild.get_role(guest))

        
client.run('Token')
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass in the id like this instead:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
 role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=955210150485057627)
 await member.add_roles(role)

client.run('Token')
```

Comment: This does not work any better than getting by id. In fact it is slower with little benefit. If you want reliability, you should be using the api call `await guild.fetch_role(12345)`.

Comment: @Eric You shouldn't spam the API, `get_role` suffices once the bot is ready.

Comment: @clan `get_role` is perfectly viable, and the method in this answer is less readable and unnecessary. All the same, if `get_role` wasn't working, they would get an error. This is not the case, so this answer is incorrect.